# Checking whether a pointer has been set to an initialized object

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a class called `Entry`:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class Entry {
public:
    Entry(K const &key, V const &val, size_t const hash_val) :
        key(key), val(val), hash_val(hash_val), empty(false){
    }

    K getKey() const {
        return key;
    }

    V getValue() const {
        return val;
    }

    size_t getHash() const {
        return hash_val;
    }

    bool isEmpty() const{
        return empty;
    }
private:
    // key-value pair
    K key;
    V val;
    // Store hash for reallocation
    size_t hash_val;
    // Store empty state
    bool empty;
};
```

Then I create an array of objects

```
Entry<K, V>** entries = new Entry<K, V> *[100];
```

If I call `entries[0]->isEmpty()`, I get a segmentation fault. This makes sense to me, since I haven't actually instantiated a new object in memory. However, I want to be able to check whether a slot in the array actually points to a valid object. Currently, I've been setting each pointer to `nullptr` so I can check for equality later, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: entries is not a pointer.  It's a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant entries[0]->pointers. Fixed!

Comment: Why not use smart pointers?

Comment: Do you expect 'holes' in initialized entries, i.e. is following expected: entry[x] = nullptr, entry[x + 1] != nullptr?

Comment: @DrewDormann I flagged this comment.

Comment: Have you considered using standard containers for this?

Comment: There is no way to do this. C++ does not work this way. It is your responsibility to access only pointers that point to valid, constructed (and not destroyed) objects. C++ will not do this for you. You will have to implement the appropriate logic that makes sure that only valid pointers are dereferenced. There are no alternatives, that's how C++ works.

Comment: the line where you declare the array is double fishy. First because you should use `std::vector`, second because the size is fixed so its not clear why you dynamically allocate it in the first place, 100 pointers isnt something that wont fit on the stack.

Comment: and 3, because chances are high that you actually want an array of objects rather than an array of pointers

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm implementing a hashmap, so I wanted to use a static array. I dynamically allocate because the array size can get very large, especially if I want to test having a lot of buckets. I am curious about using an array of objects instead of an array of pointers. I thought it wasn't possible to create an array of templated objects because of the varying size.

Comment: there are no "templated objects". `Entry` is a template. `Entry<K, V>` is a type like any other. Objects of some type are all of the same size and that size is a compile time constant

Comment: I think i already made similar comment on one of your previous questions. You need to understand that templates only exists at compile time. As soon as you have an object of some type, thats not a template anymore

Comment: There is no method to validate a pointer.  A pointer value of zero can be a valid address (like in embedded systems).  You can't tell if the Operating System will translate the address in the pointer to another block of memory.  In Embedded Systems, there many be holes in the address space (i.e. some address may have no assignments).  Stay away from pointers, prefer references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `optional`. It's *always* either a valid object, or in an "empty" state.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
  int bar;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::optional<Foo>> vfoo{
      Foo{1}, std::nullopt, Foo{2}, Foo{3}, std::nullopt,
  };

  for (auto const& foo : vfoo) {
    if (!foo)
      std::puts("Not Initialized");
    else
      std::printf("Foo{%d}\n", foo->bar);
  }
}
```

Comment: An optional pointer just makes the pointer double null able.  Which seems twice as nullable as needed

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am not using pointers in this example and I was suggesting OP shouldn't either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check if a pointer has been initialized, because reading from an unitialized pointer is undefined behavior:

```
 int* p;
 if (p == something) ...   // undefined behavior
```

You can initialize the pointer with `nullptr` and check for that:

```
 int* p = nullptr;
 if (p == nullptr) ...
```

However, then you are initializing the pointer.

For a dynamic array of `Entry<K, V>*` you can use a `std::vector<Entry<K,V>*>`. A container that can be used analogous to an array with empty slots is a `std::unordered_map`:

```
std::unordered_map<size_t,Entry<K,V>*> map;
Entry<K,V>* ptr = get_pointer_from_somewhere();
size_t index = 42;
if ( map.find(index) == map.end() ) { 
     // pointer was not initialized (actually pointer is not yet in the map)
     map.insert( { index, ptr }); // now it is
}
```

Actually `insert` alone will tell you already if the element with key `index` was present in the map before.

Comment: Maybe better to use `try_emplace`.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I think the crux if the question is just checking if the pointer was initialized, inserting was only to add something to the example. Though I got even that wrong :/ I really shouldn't post untestet code...

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin emplace for a pointer? I am not fluent with C++17, I don't see how `try_emplace` would be beneficial here